# What SQL Server database and table does Sharepoint 2010 use to hold "Issue Tracking List" data?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

Trying to track down this table, I've spot checked some 160 tables and have not been able to find the table that stores data for this list.

I have these databases created by Sharepoint 2010:

```
Application_Registry _Service  
Managed Metadata Service  
My_Portal_WSS_Content  
MySites_WSS_Content  
PerformancePoint Service Application  
Search_Service_Application_CrawlStore  
Search_Service_Application_DB  
Search_Service_Application_PropertyStoreDB  
Secure_Store_Service_DB  
SharePoint_AdminContent  
SharePoint_Config  
StateService  
User Profile Service Application_ProfileDB  
User Profile Service Application_SocialDB  
User Profile Service Application_SyncDB  
WebAnalyticsServiceApplication_ReportingDB  
WebAnalyticsServiceApplication_StagingDB  
WSS_Logging  
WSS_Search
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint uses a **single table** to store all the items from all the lists - `dbo.AllUserData`. If you need to access is directly, it is possible but cumbersome and not recommended.

Without knowing the exact configuration I can only guess that the list you're looking for is stored in the `My_Portal_WSS_Content` database.

[Inspecting The SharePoint Content Database](http://vspug.com/ethan/2007/09/16/inspecting-the-sharepoint-content-database/)